# New columns created in a table emerge in another table using data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have a data table called "dt".

```
## Generate a data table
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(A=c(1,2,3),B=c(4,5,6))
```

I want to test some information by creating new columns but I do not want to change the original table, so I create a backup table called "test".

```
## Create a backup for the original table "dt"
test = dt
```

However, when I create a new column called "C", I find it also emerges in the original table "dt".

```
## Create a new column
test[,C:=A+B]
## The new column "C" emerges in the original table "dt"
> colnames(dt)
[1] "A" "B" "C"
```

This manipulation is likely to be dangerous because it changes the original table. How can I change the test table without changing the original table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `copy` :

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(A=c(1,2,3),B=c(4,5,6))
test <- copy(dt)
test[,C:=A+B]

names(test)
#[1] "A" "B" "C"
names(dt)
#[1] "A" "B"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Could you please explain why this happens for ":=" of data.table? When I remove column C from table "test" such that "test = test[,-"C"]", it seems the original table "dt" does not change.

Comment: I am not a `data.table` expert but I think only `:=` does copy by reference which you can verify when you do `test[, C:= NULL]`